# html2pdf with image in serial letter very slow

Tags: php, html, pdf, html2pdf

I'm using html2pdf for my web project and generate a lot of PDF files.
Now I'm trying to create some serial letters with like 200 or 300 pages and each page has a logo in the header section.
If I do it, it takes like 5-10 minutes. But if I remove the logo / image from every page it only takes like 5 seconds to create it.

**Does anyone have experiences how to optimize this performance issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the time is spend in html2pdf? Maybe the image is of very big size? Try to reduce
the dimensions of it and convert it to JPG.

You can also use the debug mode to see which part take a long time, it will help you ;)

Comment: good lawd that "debug mode" was a great hint. It was not the image, it was the table that i used for the footer :-O Thanks man!